# How to construct a file from a relative path in a File

Tags: java, nio

I'm parsing a base file at this location:
`/Users/haddad/development/fspc/content/2017.dev/src/agency/individual/integration/src/forms/print.xml`

And from that file, I parse out:
`../../../../include/masking.xml`

So that relative path is from the context from the file I parsed it out from (base file)

How can I constuct a file object from that relative path so I can read it's contents?

Comment: You can't. Your reference path has only 3 parent folders, and the relative path references 4 parents, so it is an invalid relative reference.

Comment: Did you try the [File constructor?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.io.File-java.lang.String-)

Comment: @Andreas It's a false parent path, I used it for illustrative purpose. Will correct this

Comment: @MFisherKDX I think Paths has a way of doing it. Interested to see how it can be done from my example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged `nio`, the [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class makes this easy. You simply call [`resolveSibling()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolveSibling-java.lang.String-) and [`normalize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize--).

```
String main = "/Users/haddad/development/fspc/content/2017.dev/src/agency/individual/integration/src/forms/print.xml";
String ref = "../../../../include/masking.xml";

System.out.println(Paths.get(main));
System.out.println(Paths.get(main).resolveSibling(ref));
System.out.println(Paths.get(main).resolveSibling(ref).normalize());
```

Or:

```
System.out.println(Paths.get(main));
System.out.println(Paths.get(main, ref));
System.out.println(Paths.get(main, ref).normalize());
```

*Output*

```
\Users\haddad\development\fspc\content\2017.dev\src\agency\individual\integration\src\forms\print.xml
\Users\haddad\development\fspc\content\2017.dev\src\agency\individual\integration\src\forms\..\..\..\..\include\masking.xml
\Users\haddad\development\fspc\content\2017.dev\src\agency\include\masking.xml
```

*<sup>Note: I ran this on a Window machine, so I of course got backslashes</sup>*

---

If you prefer the old [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object, you use the two-argument constructor, and call [`getCanonicalFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalFile--).

```
System.out.println(new File(main));
System.out.println(new File(main, ref));
System.out.println(new File(main, ref).getCanonicalFile());
```

*Output*

```
\Users\haddad\development\fspc\content\2017.dev\src\agency\individual\integration\src\forms\print.xml
\Users\haddad\development\fspc\content\2017.dev\src\agency\individual\integration\src\forms\print.xml\..\..\..\..\include\masking.xml
C:\Users\haddad\development\fspc\content\2017.dev\src\agency\individual\include\masking.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `subpath()` to keep the path part that interests you that you can combine with `resolve()` to append a new path to :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Path printXmlPath = Paths.get("/Users/haddad/development/fspc/content/2017.dev/src/agency/individual/integration/src/forms/print.xml");

    Path maskingXmlPath = printXmlPath.subpath(0, printXmlPath.getNameCount() - 5)
                                      .resolve("include/masking.xml");

    System.out.println(maskingXmlPath);
}
```

> Users\haddad\development\fspc\content\2017.dev\src\agency\include\masking.xml